# Python String "Modifiers"

Tags: python, django

What are these "modifiers" called on the front of a python string?  I don't understand what these are used for.  Also, since I don't know what they are called, I don't know what to search for to learn about them (or the others that may be available if any).

In this example what does the "u" represent on the front of the string in the return?

```
 def __unicode__(self):
        return u'title: %s, text: %s, created:%s, tags: %s' % (self.title, self.text, self.created, self.tags)
```

In this django URL example, what does the "r" represent?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I'm learning python and django and I see these in examples, but do not have an explanation of what they represent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'r' indicates a raw string, which alters the escaping behavior. This is useful for regular expressions to make them easier to read. The 'u' indicates that it is a Unicode string. They're called **[string literal prefixes](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings)**.

From the docs:

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences. A prefix of 'u' or 'U' makes the string a Unicode string. Unicode strings use the Unicode character set as defined by the Unicode Consortium and ISO 10646. Some additional escape sequences, described below, are available in Unicode strings. A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be followed by an 'r' prefix.
>
> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

Comment: `r` is *useful* for writing regular expressions, but it stands for "raw" -- escapes sequences not interpreted.

Comment: Voted up because no RTFM attitude or links. ^5

Comment: "Explicitly declared as Unicode" is misleading. A string and a Unicode string are two different objects in Python 2. There is no implicit conversion anywhere.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I disagree that it's misleading. This is an explicit way to define a string literal as unicode type versus using something implicit like "from __future__ import unicode_literals". I think it's valuable to point out the need for "being explicit" with the declaration of literals in Py 2. It's certainly confusing if you're coming from other languages that don't have the distinction (or just coming from Py 3).

Comment: @TroyHoward You would rather not know where the material comes from, and rather not be able to easily read about the topic at greater length?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Python3.3 will have the u prefix available, but it will neither be explicit nor implicit because in 3k it will have no impact on the string. It's sole function will be to make porting to 3k easier from 2k. see PEP 414

Comment: @Marcin Well, the best is a link plus a quote, not either or... but a quote is better than a link if you need to pick one. Links can die rapidly or may not be very specific in terms of directing you to the relevant part. For example all three posts included the same link, which just goes to the general section about string literals (because that's as specific as you can get with a link) whereas the relevant part is a chunk of the second paragraph down the page from there, which is what John Sheehan quoted. Providing the link alone obscures access to the relevant information.

Comment: Just a note that there is an 'f' prefix now that allows for formatting. It can be used in conjunction with other prefixes such as 'r'. Example `print(f'__name__ = {__name__}')`

Answer (score 3):

These differ between Python 2 and Python 3:

Python 2:

```
 "hello" # Normal string (8-bit characters)
u"hello" # Unicode string
r"hello" # Raw string --> Backslashes don't need to be escaped
b"hello" # treated like normal string, to ease transition from 2 to 3
```

Python 3:

```
 "hello" # Unicode string
b"hello" # Bytes object. Not a string!
r"hello" # Raw string --> Backslashes don't need to be escaped
u"hello" # Python 3.3, treated like Unicode string, to ease transition from 2 to 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are called string literals:  http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Example, r' ' is raw and won't have the same escaping

Comment: Answers which are merely links are discouraged.

Comment: You really downvoted me for linking to the exact docs explaining in detail the question he asked? I highly doubt that repeating or fully quoting docs on here is encouraged over linking to them with the answer to the question and an example.

Comment: oh, it was so you could use my same link and try to get the accept? Classy.

Comment: Actually, repeating or fully quoting the docs is exactly what is encouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Answer (score -4):

Use the docs, Luke: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

u = Unicode string (each item represents a unicode code point)

r = raw string (escapes are just an ordinary sequence of characters, useful for regexes)

b/no prefix = byte string (each item is a byte). Note that in python 3, no prefix means a unicode string.

Comment: I think it's the condescension in the first sentence. You're basically saying, "RTFM" when the poster said they couldn't find the info because they didn't know what it was called.

Comment: @JohnSheehan Perhaps. The use did not fail to find this information because he "didn't know what it was called" - he failed to find it because he didn't bother to read the standard documentation for the language he is using.